# Angular Remove Google map Markers

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to remove all markers from map on button click;

```
gmarkers = []; //define empty array for all markers
```

Add markers, show map:

```
addMarkersToMap(markers) { 
    for(let marker of markers) {
    var  position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude,   marker.longitude);
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       title: marker.name
     });
     myMarker(this.map);
     this.gmarkers.push(marker); //push all markers to gmarkers array
   }
}
```

Remove markers:

```
removeMarkers(){
  if (this.gmarkers) {
      for (let i in this.gmarkers) {
        this.gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }

      this.gmarkers = [];
   }
}
```

Also try with this approach to remove:

```
removeMarkers(){
    for(var i=0; i<this.gmarkers.length; i++){
      this.gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
   this.gmarkers = [];
}
```

I got error:

> this.gmarkers[i].setMap is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : Use `foreach` instead

```
removeMarkers(){
    this.gmarkers.foreach((marker)=>{
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker = null;
    })
   this.gmarkers = [];
}
```

And In your `addMarkersToMap()` method, you are pushing the `marker` variable, instead you need to push `myMarker` inside `gmarkers` I guess.

```
addMarkersToMap(markers) { 
    for(let marker of markers) {
    var  position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude,   marker.longitude);
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       title: marker.name
     });
     myMarker(this.map);
     //replace marker with myMarker
     this.gmarkers.push(myMarker); //push all markers to gmarkers array
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, I tried this approach, but again there is same error. Do I need to post rest of code, maybe is there some kind of code which causes problems?

Comment: In your `addMarkersToMap()` method, you are pushing the `marker` variable, instead you need to push `myMarker` inside `gmarkers` I guess.

Comment: It seems that I was watching in wrong method to find error.. Thank you for your time, now it works nice!

Comment: the codes do not seems to be angular / typescript. why do the title says "angular?